# Angular 6 TypeError: guard is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, routes

I'm trying to implement just a simple guard :

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    console.log('guarded ?!?');

    return true;
}
```

And use it in my app routing module :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        component: UnauthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { excludeLogin: true },
        children: [
          { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { requireLogin: true },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: RequestContainerComponent,
            children: [
              { path: 'list', component: RequestListComponent },
              { path: 'results/:id', component: RequestResultListComponent},
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      enableTracing: false,
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

In the auth.module :

```
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
],
```

In the app.module :

```
imports: [
    AuthModule,
]
```

But I get this error, I have no idea why ?

Comment: Have you added the route guard to the list of providers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AuthGuard` is essentially a service and should be registered to your AppModule. Add the `AuthGuard` to the `providers` array in `app.module.ts`.

Edit: per conversation below, the problem came from using `canActivateChild` in routes when AuthGuard implements `CanActivate`.

Comment: My guard is provided in a authenticate.module that is imported in my app.module, isn't that enough ?

Comment: @An-droid Did you also export it?

Comment: If I export it I get this : `Can't export value AuthGuard from AuthModule as it was neither declared nor imported!`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. Wasn't thinking straight

Comment: If I don't provide it or if I provide it in the app.module for example I get the same `guard is not a function` error

Comment: Oh I see. You implemented `canActivate` but are using `canActivateChild`

Comment: Omg you saved me, it's been 2hour since I got the "explicit" error, thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)